# Retrieving a value from inside a lambda expression (attempting to make a multiple choice quiz java fx)

Tags: java, eclipse, object, javafx, lambda

can anyone help me solve how to get this value out of my lambda function? Or better yet give any suggestions as to a better way to make this multiple choice quiz? The reason I need the method to return an integer is so that when the user is done taking the quiz, then can hit a button that gives them the results of their quiz. Thanks in advance !

```
    HashMap<MenuItem, Integer>thisQues1 = new HashMap<MenuItem, Integer>();
    thisQues1.put(ratq1MenuItem1, 1);
    thisQues1.put(ratq1MenuItem2, 2);
    thisQues1.put(ratq1MenuItem3, 3);
    thisQues1.put(ratq1MenuItem4, 4);
    thisQues1.put(ratq1MenuItem5, 5);

    ArrayList<MenuItem>thisGuy = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    thisGuy.add(ratq1MenuItem1);
    thisGuy.add(ratq1MenuItem2);
    thisGuy.add(ratq1MenuItem3);
    thisGuy.add(ratq1MenuItem4);
    thisGuy.add(ratq1MenuItem5);




        AtomicInteger thatGuy = new AtomicInteger();


        for (MenuItem menuItem : thisGuy) {




            menuItem.setOnAction((ActionEvent e)->{

            q1TextBox.setText(thisQues1.get(menuItem).toString());



            thatGuy.getAndAdd(thisQues1.get(menuItem));
        });


    }
```

**strong text**
    }[This is a picture of the scene of my gui Im working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgq5d.png)

Comment: You can get some ideas from https://github.com/sedj601/QuestionGameWithSQLite/tree/master/src/questongamewithsqlite.

Comment: [mcve] please .. focus on _one single_ problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I figured out the solution was actually to use a global variable, and then update it with the word this aka "this.variableName". Then I could use that to access it in another later method.

Comment: while static scope is an option it's usually the worst - don't use it!